# How to set the background image width using CSS?

Tags: css, width, background-image

I need to set the fixed width for the background image. It should work fine in both IE and Firefox. How to do get this ?

Comment: Do you want to remove repetition of background image. if so set no-repeat attribute.

Comment: I dont want to repeat and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Multiplexer: You currently can't set the width/height of the background image, but you can set the width/height of its container.

E.g.

```
<div style="background: url(someimage.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; height: 300px; width: 400px">
  Some content
</div>
```

If `someimage.jpg` is 640x480, only 400px of that width and 300px of that height will be shown. You can move the background around by playing with the background position properties of the CSS -- see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp for the full/short-hand reference.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css3 property `background-size`, but it's not fully supported yet

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-background-size

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with background-size.

```
enter code here
.myCss
{
    background-image:url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background size:10% 100%; 
}
```

In size,
10% is width value and 1005 is height value.